TRUE/FALSE is all group members sitting in consecutive seats
I'd like to create a column that tells me whether or not a group are sitting next to each other.
To visualise, my ideal output would be:



Group Number
Seat
consecutive?




1
A
Y


1
B
Y


1
C
Y


2
B
N


2
E
N



I've tried using cumsum() and ave() inspired by other answers but I cant seem to make it do what I'm after.

In your example data, you could find if the letters in seat are consecutive by matching them to the inherent LETTERS values, then using all(diff(...) == 1) to test if they are consecutive. Using dplyr::mutate:
library(dplyr)

xx %>%
  mutate(new = all(diff(match(seat, LETTERS)) == 1),
         .by = group)

Output:
#  group seat consecutive   new
#1     1    A           Y  TRUE
#2     1    B           Y  TRUE
#3     1    C           Y  TRUE
#4     2    B           N FALSE
#5     2    E           N FALSE

Here I left it as a boolean, but can add an ifelse to convert that to Y/N
Data
xx <- read.table(text = "group  seat    consecutive
1   A   Y
1   B   Y
1   C   Y
2   B   N
2   E   N", h = TRUE)

